# 500 error with urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code:

```
   req = urllib.request.Request(url=r"http://borel.slu.edu/cgi-bin/cc.cgi?foirm_ionchur=im&foirm=Seol&hits=1&format=xml",headers={'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'})
   handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

is giving me the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Foo/lang/old/test.py", line 46, in <module>
    rip()
  File "C:/Users/Foo/lang/old/test.py", line 36, in rip
    handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 138, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 375, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 487, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 413, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 495, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

but it works fine in my browser, whats the issue?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you catch the exception and call `.read()` on that, you get an XML document that looks like a successful response.

Comment: It just always replies with status 500, in browsers as well.

Answer (score 19):

The server is rather b0rken. It responds with a 500 error in the *browser* as well.

You can catch the exception and still read the response:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

req = urllib.request.Request(url=r"http://borel.slu.edu/cgi-bin/cc.cgi?foirm_ionchur=im&foirm=Seol&hits=1&format=xml",headers={'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'})
try:
    handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    content = e.read()
```

Comment: If you're like me and got an error about urllib.error not being defined, and you're actually using urllib2, try `from urllib2 import HTTPError` instead

Answer (score 1):

When it happened to me I've reduced the plt.figure size parameter and it worked. It may be some odd parameter on your code that is not being able to be read.