# I'm trying to download some image from whatsapp web

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib, urllib3

I found a way to identify the images but idk how to get their URL.

part of the code:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
    sticker = # <idk how to get the URL> 
    url.urlretrieve(sticker)
```

btw if there's a best way to download the, I'll be glad to hear some advises.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```py
src = image.get_attribute('src')

# download the image
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "image.png")
```

This assumes there is an attribute src in the image tag.

Comment: i actually get this error:

raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Comment: Not sure why that is, maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912257/500-error-with-urllib-request-urlopen